# is it possible in Javascript to have a clipped object repeat on the other side of the screen?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, three.js

I recently got into javascript and was wondering if it was possible to have an object clip off a screen and have the missing part appear on the other end of the screen as if the page was continuous. I attached an illustration below to better explain what I mean.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DCpZN.jpg

Comment: Do you want to animate the image left to right in a loop?

Comment: Put two same-style elements, one for each clip part

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please review [`How do I ask a good question?`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and consider providing a [`Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (using [`snippets`](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)) to **show us what you've tried**.

Comment: Since you've tagged three.js, I'm assuming your question is less related to javascript and more how to achieve wraparound in three.js and/or HTML Canvas, correct? Search for examples using wraparound with three.js or HTML canvas and see how others have done it.  Or search for a specific example (e.g. three.js asteroids - http://www.somethinglikecorkscrews.com/)

Comment: I tried searching for things last night but didn't know what to search for. But thank you for the asteroids example it is pretty much what I am talking about. Is there a technical name for this type of effect that will help find more examples of it?

Comment: I believe the phrase you're looking for this effect is "wrap-around." That said, again I stress: **Please show what you have tried so far.** Otherwise the answer to your question is simply "Yes," and moves into off-topic/overly-broad territory.

Comment: i got it working in three js by grabbing some lines from the asteroids example yesterday, thank you this is resolved now

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS to do this.

```css
#lp{
position:absolute;
left:-120px;
}

#rp{
position:absolute;
right:-330px;
}
```

```html
<div>

<img id='lp' src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3211/chimp-thinking.jpg">
<img id='rp'  src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3211/chimp-thinking.jpg">

</div>
```